# if and else if conditons inside a while loop

Tags: c

I have the following code for running 3 steppers at a time with different numbers of steps `n1`, `n2` and `n3`.  It does not run the `n3` motor if used as follows, but if we remove the `if` condition then it runs.

```
int n1 = 0;
int n2 = 0;
int n3 = 100
while (n1 > 0 || n2 > 0 || n3 > 0) {
    if (n3 > 0 && n1 == 0 && n2 == 0) {
        current_port_value = XGpio_DiscreteRead(&GpioOutput, LED_CHANNEL);
        new_port_value = (current_port_value & ~0X02);
        XGpio_DiscreteWrite( & GpioOutput, LED_CHANNEL, new_port_value);
        current_port_value = XGpio_DiscreteRead(&GpioOutput, LED_CHANNEL);
        new_port_value = (current_port_value | 0X04);
        XGpio_DiscreteWrite( & GpioOutput, LED_CHANNEL, new_port_value);
        current_port_value = XGpio_DiscreteRead(&GpioOutput, LED_CHANNEL);
        new_port_value = (current_port_value | 0X08);
        XGpio_DiscreteWrite( & GpioOutput, LED_CHANNEL, new_port_value);
        current_port_value = XGpio_DiscreteRead(&GpioOutput, LED_CHANNEL);
        new_port_value = (current_port_value | 0X40);
        XGpio_DiscreteWrite( & GpioOutput, LED_CHANNEL, new_port_value);
        current_port_value = XGpio_DiscreteRead(&GpioOutput, LED_CHANNEL);
        new_port_value = (current_port_value | 0X80);
        XGpio_DiscreteWrite( & GpioOutput, LED_CHANNEL, new_port_value);
        for (Delay = 0; Delay < LED_DELAY; Delay++);
        current_port_value = XGpio_DiscreteRead(&GpioOutput, LED_CHANNEL);
        new_port_value = (current_port_value & ~0X80);
        XGpio_DiscreteWrite( & GpioOutput, LED_CHANNEL, new_port_value);
        for (Delay = 0; Delay < LED_DELAY; Delay++);
    }
    n1--;
    n2--;
    n3--;
}
```

Comment: Remove all of this mess from within the `if` and examine the values in some debugger.

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: The `if` block will run exactly once as-is.  First iteration of the loop, `n1`, `n2`, and `n3` will obviously have their initial values – `0`, `0`, and `100` respectively.  Second iteration, `n1`, `n2`, and `n3` will have the values `-1`, `-1`, and `99` respectively because you are decrementing each of them after the `if` block.  Clearly it is not true that `n3 > 0 && n1 == 0 && n2 == 0` on second iteration then.

Comment: i want to run stepper motor with different number of steps,so i have different if and else if conditions...after every single step, decrement is done, while loop is present if all are 0 then our task is done

Comment: jOe3gan sir so what can i do to assure if n1 and n2 are 0 they should not decrease ??

Comment: or i can put if if (n3 > 0 && n1 <= 0 && n2 <=0) that will be right?? sir j0e3gan

Comment: `if (n1 > 0) n1--;`  Same idea for `n2` of course.

Comment: @CHANNAR Before decrementing, check if each number is 0, and only decrement if it's not.

Comment: i m doing the same thanx for helping me out

Comment: but sir j0e3gan can we use two if's inside a while?

Comment: @CHANNAR, of course you can – e.g. `while (loopCondition) { ... if (if1Condition) { ... } ... if (if2Condition) { ... } ... }` or `while (loopCondition) { ... if (if1Condition) { ... if (if2Condition) { ... } ... } ... }`.

Comment: `What do you want it to do?` (Kevin) *The `if` block will run exactly once as-is. First …* Don't comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit you question. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make it answerable, even *good*.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` block will run exactly once as-is.  First iteration of the loop, `n1`, `n2`, and `n3` will obviously have their initial values – `0`, `0`, and `100` respectively.  Second iteration, `n1`, `n2`, and `n3` will have the values `-1`, `-1`, and `99` respectively because you are decrementing each of them after the `if` block.  Clearly it is not true that `n3 > 0 && n1 == 0 && n2 == 0` on second iteration then.

My sense regarding your immediate issue then, confirmed by your comments, is that you do not want the numbers of steps (`n1`, `n2`, or `n3`) to be negative.  Using `n1` as an example, *simply do not decrement numbers of steps when they are not greater than or equal to one – e.g. change* `n1--;` *to* `if (n1 > 0) n1--;`.